# Robot Framework - How to get text of an element that then use that text in another keyword

Tags: robotframework

I have a test case where I register an account with a unique email address.

What I want to do is sign out and sign back into the account using the newly created email address.
I have a keyword that gets the text of the email from the My account section

**Get email address**

```
${email}  get text  ${contact_email}
[Return]  ${email}
```

I then have another keyword that signs into the account.

**Enter Newly Registrered Email**

```
input text  ${signin_email}
```

What I want to be able to do is pass the email address that I have gotten from the 'get text' into that test case.

Has anyone any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 4):

Assign the value of `${email}` you get from **Get Email Address** to a variable (f.e. `${new_email}`) and use it as an argument for **Enter Newly Registrered Email**:

```
${new_email}=    Get Email Adress
Enter Newly Registrered Email   ${new_email}
```

You have to define **Enter Newly Registrered Email** so that it uses an argument:

```
Enter Newly Registrered Email
    [Arguments]    ${signing_email}
    input text  ${signing_email}
```

If you want to do it in different test case you have to make `${new_email}` a suite variable:

```
Set Suite Variable    ${new_email}
```

---

Further readings:

- [User keyword arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.0/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-arguments).
- [Variable priorities and scopes](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.0/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-priorities-and-scopes)